# Gradle: get only task names

Tags: gradle, gradlew

For the purposes of build automation I need to be able to execute a number of gradle tasks matching a given pattern, process the assembled result, clean up a bit, and then do another task in a list. To that end i need to get all the task names and nothing but the names from gradle. However, when i say `./gradlew -tasks` I also get task descriptions and some other text i don't need.

Is there a key I might pass to gradle to get *only* task names? Quick googling yielded no results (yet).

Answer (score 1):

You can get all task names in the current context from taskGraph

```groovy
task printTasks << {
    def listTasks = gradle.taskGraph.getAllTasks();
    listTasks.each { logger.lifecycle(it.name) }
}
```

to skip execution of other tasks use below code

```groovy
gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {taskGraph ->
    if(taskGraph.hasTask(printTasks)){
        def tasks = taskGraph.getAllTasks()
        tasks.each {
            if(it != printTasks){
                it.enabled = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### usage

`gradle printTasks task1 task2 task3`
it would print all the tasks defined and dependant tasks as well;

Answer (score 0):

build.gradle

```groovy
task outputTasksMatching << {
    String taskPattern = properties.taskPattern
    if (!taskPattern) throw new RuntimeException("taskPattern property not specified")
    tasks.all { Task task ->
       if (task.name.matches(taskPattern)) {
          println "$task.name - $task.description"
       }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```groovy
> gradle -PtaskPattern=foo.* outputTasksMatching
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about programmatically embedding Gradle, you could use the [Tooling API](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/embedding.html). You can use this to access Gradle projects and programtically make decisions (like the one you are describing).

Here is a quick example I ran with Gradle 2.13 and the JUnit 5 project:

```groovy
//build.gradle
plugins {
  id 'groovy'
  id 'java-gradle-plugin'
}
// some other things...
dependencies {
  localGroovy()
}
```

Connecting to a project:

```java
import org.gradle.tooling.BuildLauncher;
import org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnector;
import org.gradle.tooling.ProjectConnection;
import org.gradle.tooling.model.DomainObjectSet;
import org.gradle.tooling.model.GradleProject;
import org.gradle.tooling.model.GradleTask;

import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class UsingGradleToolingApi {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    final Path junit5 = Paths.get("/Users/mkobit/Workspace/personal/junit/junit5");
    final ProjectConnection connection = GradleConnector.newConnector()
                                                        .forProjectDirectory(junit5.toFile())
                                                        .connect();


    final GradleProject gradleProject = connection.getModel(GradleProject.class);

    final DomainObjectSet<? extends GradleTask> tasks = gradleProject.getTasks();

    final List<? extends GradleTask> tasksToRun = tasks.stream()
           .filter(task -> task.getName().matches("spotless.*"))
           .peek(task -> System.out.println("Filtered task: " + task))
           .collect(Collectors.toList());


    final BuildLauncher buildLauncher = connection.newBuild();
    buildLauncher.setStandardOutput(System.out)
        .setStandardError(System.err)
        .forTasks(tasksToRun)
        .run();

    connection.close();
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Filtered task: LaunchableGradleProjectTask{path=':spotlessApply',public=false}
Filtered task: LaunchableGradleProjectTask{path=':spotlessCheck',public=false}
Filtered task: LaunchableGradleProjectTask{path=':spotlessDocumentationApply',public=false}
Filtered task: LaunchableGradleProjectTask{path=':spotlessDocumentationCheck',public=false}
Filtered task: LaunchableGradleProjectTask{path=':spotlessGroovyApply',public=false}
Filtered task: LaunchableGradleProjectTask{path=':spotlessGroovyCheck',public=false}
Filtered task: LaunchableGradleProjectTask{path=':spotlessJavaApply',public=false}
Filtered task: LaunchableGradleProjectTask{path=':spotlessJavaCheck',public=false}
Filtered task: LaunchableGradleProjectTask{path=':spotlessMiscApply',public=false}
Filtered task: LaunchableGradleProjectTask{path=':spotlessMiscCheck',public=false}
[versioning] WARNING - the working copy has unstaged or uncommitted changes.
[versioning] WARNING - the working copy has unstaged or uncommitted changes.
[versioning] WARNING - the working copy has unstaged or uncommitted changes.
[versioning] WARNING - the working copy has unstaged or uncommitted changes.
[versioning] WARNING - the working copy has unstaged or uncommitted changes.
[versioning] WARNING - the working copy has unstaged or uncommitted changes.
[versioning] WARNING - the working copy has unstaged or uncommitted changes.
[versioning] WARNING - the working copy has unstaged or uncommitted changes.
[versioning] WARNING - the working copy has unstaged or uncommitted changes.
[versioning] WARNING - the working copy has unstaged or uncommitted changes.
[versioning] WARNING - the working copy has unstaged or uncommitted changes.
[versioning] WARNING - the working copy has unstaged or uncommitted changes.
:spotlessDocumentationApply
:spotlessGroovyApply
:spotlessJavaApply
:spotlessMiscApply
:spotlessApply
:spotlessDocumentationCheck
:spotlessGroovyCheck
:spotlessJavaCheck
:spotlessMiscCheck
:spotlessCheck

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 0.87 secs

Process finished with exit code 0
```